# Wierd name displayed by git status

Tags: git, file, rename, filenames, git-status

When i rename part of file from hyphen to underscore original name of file in git status

For example `My-file.examaple` wil became `My\342\200\223file.example`.

But wierd is when I use Jetbrains gui for commit it shows the right file name.

Comment: You wrote an en-dash (`–` U+2013 EN DASH) in your filename, not an underscore. Git escapes non-Unicode with your current configuration (explained by the previous comment).

Comment: “escapes non-Unicode”—I meant to write non-Ascii. :)